# SQL Server : reset Id and recreate data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am looking for a way to reset primary key Ids and recreate data so they are sorted by date.

Before

```
Pk_Col Letters_Col Date_Col
------------------------------------------
1           A      2015-02-16 00:00:00.000
2           B      2012-02-16 00:00:00.000
3           C      2014-02-16 00:00:00.000
1003        D      2009-02-16 00:00:00.000
1004        E      2008-02-16 00:00:00.000
1902        F      2016-02-16 00:00:00.000
```

After / desired output

```
Pk_Col Letters_Col Date_Col
------------------------------------------
1           E      2008-02-16 00:00:00.000
2           D      2009-02-16 00:00:00.000
3           B      2012-02-16 00:00:00.000
4           C      2014-02-16 00:00:00.000
5           A      2015-02-16 00:00:00.000
6           F      2016-02-16 00:00:00.000
```

I've tried so far:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.myTable',RESEED,0);    

INSERT INTO dbo.myTable (Letters_Col, Date_Col)
   SELECT 
      Letters_Col, Date_Col
   FROM 
      (DELETE FROM myTable OUTPUT deleted.*) d;
```

I have to include query below probably but I had no luck to run this query successfully with recreating data and sorting at one time:

```
select * 
from myTable 
order by cast([Date_Col] as datetime) asc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be dangerous to reset primary keys.  After all, they are used for foreign key relationships, so another table might be referencing them.  And, the key itself should not have any particular meaning.

However, you can do what you want using ranking functions and `update`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum
      from myTable t
     )
update toupdate
    set pk_Col = seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update `PK_Col` and there isn't any *foreign key*:

```
UPDATE dbo.myTable 
SET PK_Col = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM dbo.myTable ti 
              WHERE ti.DateCol <= dbo.myTable.DateCol And 
                    ti.PK_Col <= dbo.myTable.PK_Col)
```